# Java Swing - setting margins on TextArea with Line Border

Tags: java, swing, textarea, margins, insets

As the title says, I am simply trying to set the margins (provide some padding) on a TextArea with a LineBorder set. Without setting the Border, .setMargins works fine. Here is the specific chunk of code.

```
aboutArea = new JTextArea("program info etc.....");

Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);

aboutArea.setSize(400, 200);
aboutArea.setBorder(border);
aboutArea.setEditable(false);
aboutArea.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12));

add(aboutArea);
```

I have tried each of these:

```
aboutArea.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
.getBorders(aboutArea).set(10,10,10,10);
UIManager.put("aboutArea.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

but nothing affects the margins after I apply the border, the padding is always 0. Any ideas how to set the padding on the textArea with the border?

Comment: The key for the `JTextArea` margin is `"TextArea.margin"`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What if you  try adding a [CompoundBorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createCompoundBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border,%20javax.swing.border.Border%29) , won't this do, this will give you almost same thing

```
JTextArea tarea = new JTextArea("program info etc.");
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
tarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, 
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
```

[image: CHECK THE MIDDLE JTextArea as OUTPUT]

Comment: @Daniel everything depends if JTextArea is or isn't placed inside JScrollPane +1

Comment: +1, but (tilts head) as to the screenshot, why not put the GUI in front of a plain white BG?  E.G.  Ctrl-t While I am in FF and a get a white space of over half screen size.  For further tips, see [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Comment: @mKorbel  You reminded me that I usually add the component to a `JPanel` then set the border to the panel.  It works flawlessly for scroll-panes, buttons, labels..

Comment: I try to place my open window on any white space of stackoverflow page, sometimes I forget to remove my console from beneath my top window, seems like that's what is wrong with my image ?

Comment: @nIcE cOw hehehe sometimes is better to play "Fail to React"