# padding of JTable via JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have `JTable` in `JScrollPane`.

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.setViewportView(table);
```

everything is well, but If I need to be more space between Scrollpanel and table? how can I do that? for example: in `HTML/CSS` if we use `<div>` tag, we have "padding" method. I need something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another solution is

```
setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10), new EtchedBorder()));
```

it does not deletes black lines around the component too, which is inside the ScrollPanel.

Comment: Or you can use a `LineBorder` in conjuction with `EmptyBorder`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275226/1057230). +1 for the find :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: yes. that's which I needed. BUY id deletes black border around the table. I need that border color too.

Comment: if I create BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK) there is too big border. the solution using BORDER is not good. I need Padding, not border with hidden color.