# Getting pixels between border of TextArea and text inside

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

[image]

I wish to obtain and modify the number of pixels between the text contained inside the text area and the border of the text area. To provide a more descriptive visual:

[image]

where the length of the blue line is what I desired. When I received both the padding and margins of the text area in my application, I got 0px. I assume that this is the padding/margin of the TextArea relative to the outside, not the inside relative to the Ttext area.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you are trying to achieve, maybe there is a better of achieving the same result without mucking with the defaults.

Comment: @AravindChennuru Okay, I'll start from the top: I am trying to make the text area dynamically change its height in order to fit the text inside (without excess). Prior to this question, I did this by creating a `Text` with the font and text equal to that of the text area. In addition, I would set the wrapping width equal to the text area width. Finally, I would take its height and set the text area height to that. However, when testing, I realized I would need to account for the space between the text and text area, and set wrapping width of text to TextArea#width - left space - right space.

Comment: The question asks for a method to get said left space and right space between the contained text and the text area. I would prefer to stick my method of dynamically sizing the text area as, without accounting for the blue lines in my question, the height is only slightly off (as I am not accounting for the blue lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `java` to set the `insets` of a `textarea` you can use `setMargin()`.

> **public void setMargin(Insets m)**
>
> Sets margin space between the text
>   component's border and its text. The text component's default Border
>   object will use this value to create the proper margin. However, if a
>   non-default border is set on the text component, it is that Border
>   object's responsibility to create the appropriate margin space (else
>   this property will effectively be ignored). This causes a redraw of
>   the component. A PropertyChange event ("margin") is sent to all
>   listeners.
>
> **Parameters:** m - the space between the border and the text

**for example:**

```
JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea("Hello world!");
txtArea.setMargin( new Insets(15,15,15,15) );
```

more on [insets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html) and [setMargin()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29).

Or another approach would be to add a `compound border` and then setting the `insets` on it like this:

```
 JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea("Hello world!");
 Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED);
 txtArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
       border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15))
 );
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274750/java-swing-setting-margins-on-textarea-with-line-border).

Comment: Okay, so this cleared up the concept between padding and margins (called insets in JavaFX). Any idea why the padding would be returned as 0 in my case? When I can access my computer I will check whether negative padding would reverse the direction the padding is applied (making the contained text take up more space).

Comment: @MarDev I will now add an example on how to `obtain the padding value` from `javascript` and change it on either just `one element` or `all elements of the same class`.

Comment: @MarDev sorry about that I misread your question tags, I thought this was `javascript` but then I saw it is `Java`. I changed the answer, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The API you're using is still Swing, not JavaFX. However, your answer helped my find out that even when my padding is 0, JavaFX will add a few pixels (as seen above). I had to set the padding to -5 to remove it. I will accept for your substantial efforts.